# import github repo to colab. Imports as notebook into google drive, not a directory

Tags: github, google-colaboratory

Basically all that I wish to do is to run the files in a github repository in colab. Some files are ipynb and some are data that they will use. I have read many posts and I have imported the github repository but I am not doing something right.

I have started a google colab from my google drive. Then I have mounted the drive with

"from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')"

And, I use "!git clone [repository address].

The repository is definitely mounted and I can see the files, some of which are data and some are python notebook files, by using "!ls".

However, when I go to my google drive, I don't see this directory but I do see a colab notebook. If I click on it I am brought to the same colab notebook that I just left. I expected that in the google drive I would see a directory with the same structure as the github repository.

Ultimately, What I want to do is to be able to run the files that are ipynb from the google drive but I am not given this option. In fact, I really don't know how I can run these ipynb files.

I am almost there but missing something simple but vital.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. Evidently, the problem was that I had not descended the directory structure on my google drive enough. Just importing to "/content/drive" imports what ever github repository as a ipynb file. I descended to '/content/drive/My Drive/projects' and imported the github repository there. It was then available in google drive as a directory, complete with ipynb files and other data.